# Failed to execute goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:6.1.0.Final:build

Tags: maven, jenkins, drools, kie

I am trying to automate build process and building rules kjar using maven , however I am getting following exception for my project :

> Failed to execute goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:6.1.0.Final:build
>   (default-build) on project testProject: Execution default-build of
>   goal org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:6.1.0.Final:build failed: Cannot find
>   KieModule

I am giving maven command to execute my build :

> " mvn clean package"

.
Any help is appreciated .

Thanks
XslGuy

Comment: The Maven build is OK on your machine? Did you try to use the -U option to force the dependencies resolution? On your Jenkins server, did you check your ~/.m2/repository folder (to verify if the relevant dependency is here)?

Comment: I did check local repo for dependencies and it is in place , I tried with -U option but getting the same error . Another thing I don't have any java code as such and I want to build kjar for rdslr files.

Comment: I don't think you can execute Drools rules without any Java code.

Comment: I am not executing drools rule , I just want to build kjar and install it in maven repo.